# How could I apply these movement codes in a Matrix?

Tags: java, swing, matrix, awt, keypress

Right now, i have this code that creates a circle which i can move around using the keyboards.

```
public class mov extends JPanel implements ActionListener,KeyListener{
Timer t=new Timer(100, this);
double x=100,y=100,velx=0,vely=0;

public mov(){
    t.start();
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setColor(Color.red);
    g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y,40,40)); 
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    repaint();
    x = x+velx;
    y = y+vely;
}

public void up(){
    vely=-50;
    velx=0;
}

public void down(){
    vely=50;
    velx=0;
}

public void left(){
    velx=-50;
    vely=0;
}

public void right(){
    velx=50;
    vely=0;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int code=e.getKeyCode();
    if(code==KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        up();
    }
    if(code==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        down();
    }
    if(code==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        left();
    }
    if(code==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        right();
    }
}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    vely=0;
    velx=0;
}
```

I have to do this but with elements in a matrix, eg:

```
[x,x,x,x,x]
[x,x,o,x,x]
[x,x,x,x,x]
```

When up arrow key is pressed should switch to:

```
[x,x,o,x,x]
[x,x,x,x,x]
[x,x,x,x,x]
```

I know it's not with the x+xspeed way I'm doing it but rather with changing the matrix[n][m] position, But I'm not sure how to go about doing this using methods in a similar way to my code.
My main Doubt would be how to apply it, because here the repaint() method is what makes the ball "disappear" and "reappear" in the new xy position.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The only difference I see is that your up/down/left/right methods would simply change the values held by your matrix. How *exactly* they'd change it would depend (I believe) on background information that I don't see you've posted yet, including precisely what the matrix is filled with (x and o chars? ints?, booleans?) and how exactly the matrix would be used.

Comment: It would be filled with either graphics or images which should be shown in a JFrame (a small "get to the goal" game i'm doing). There would also be elements in the matrix that would be 'walls' which wouldnt be passable